# Term for: There Exists a Rational between every two Rationals?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology, foundations

The integers and the rationals have the same cardinality, but the rationals satisfy the property that:

$$
\forall p,q\in\mathbb{Q},\quad \exists r\in\mathbb{Q}\quad \textrm{s.t.}\quad p<r<q,
$$

while the integers don't.

Is there a term for this property?

Comment: Since you tagged the question as *foundations*, you might want to google the terms *dense linear order* and *dense linear order without endpoins*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Such an order on a set is called a [dense order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_order).

The notion of [dense in topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_set) is closely related to the one in order theory. See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2816/dense-in-terms-of-order-and-in-terms-of-the-order-topology) answer.